# Console error :- Vue js No app record id found for instance

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I sometimes get a weird error in console in vue js app not sure what is causing it.
I am using vue 2.6.11 and oidc-client and vue sidebar menu

sharing details as below
[image]

Comment: Hard to help with just this IMO. Tried in a different browser? The error may be more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a vue-devtools issue. If you turn off 'Update tracking' it should solve the issue.

[https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/issues/1791](https://github.com/vuejs/devtools/issues/1791#issuecomment-1067073241)